# "Quantifiers map Boolean algebras into Boolean algebras"

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, set-theory, model-theory, boolean-algebra

(The questions I have I believe relate to the answer given by Eric Wofsey to this question: [Generalised quantifiers and Boolean Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2153467/generalised-quantifiers-and-boolean-algebra)).

In Richard Zuber's ["Generalised quantifiers and the semantics of the same."](http://journals.linguisticsociety.org/proceedings/index.php/SALT/article/view/2598) (published online in N. Ashton, et al. (Eds.), Proceedings of SALT 21, e-Language, pp. 515–531,  http://dx.doi.org/10.3765/salt.v21i0.2598), Zuber writes (p.518, $\textit{op cit.}$) that

> "Quantifiers are specific functions having Boolean structure, that is functions forming (pointwise) a Boolean algebra and mapping a Boolean algebra into a Boolean algebra."

- In what sense do quantifiers map Boolean algebras into Boolean algebras? (Does it bear any relation to what is said in the following two references ([1] and [2]) about quantifiers being closure operators, mapping Boolean algebras onto themselves

[1] https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EkIL1BYKjlgC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=additive+closure+operator+quantifiers&source=bl&ots=iGnCVKqXq9&sig=gJhO9IUW38qgYZqccLPvA9nvkZ0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ8eLqubXSAhVNFMAKHQeICBcQ6AEISjAJ#v=onepage&q=additive%20closure%20operator%20quantifiers&f=false

[2] https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=awNYCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=additive+closure+operator+quantifiers&source=bl&ots=sGAdG9Tl0c&sig=G3-IC5dEKarC8xFxiPfdouO-g60&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ8eLqubXSAhVNFMAKHQeICBcQ6AEINzAF#v=onepage&q=additive%20closure%20operator%20quantifiers&f=false

- Consider a type $\langle 1 \rangle$ quantifier over a universe $E$ (where a type $\langle 1 \rangle$ quantifier is a function from sets (sub-sets
  of a universe $E$) to truth values), such as $\textit{Every boy}$. $\textit{Every boy}$ is a function which takes a set, say the set of sleeping individuals, to $TRUE$ iff every boy sleeps. But in what sense does such a quantifier map a Boolean algebra into a Boolean algebra? Could you give an intuitive example?
- Furthermore, is this mapping established by a type $\langle 1 \rangle$ quantifier a homomorphism? (Also, must it be a homomorphism?)
- What does it mean to say (as Zuber says in the above quotation) that the functions form $\textit{pointwise}$ a Boolean algebra?

More generally, the author speaks frequently of functions having a "boolean structure".

- What precisely could this mean?

Comment: See Jouko Vaananen, [Models and Games](https://books.google.it/books?id=uDDDbkfZpIEC&pg=PA283) ,Cambridge (2011), **Ch.10 Generalized Quantifiers** : "**Definition 10.1** A *weak (generalized) quantifier* is a mapping $Q$ which maps
every non-empty set $A$ to a subset of $\mathcal P(A)$. A weak (generalized) quantifier *on* a domain $A$ is any subset of $\mathcal P(A)$."

Comment: Example: for a domain $A$, the universal quant $\forall$ is the mapping $\forall (A) = \{ X \subseteq A : X = A \} = \{ A \}$ (quite obviously).

Comment: And $\exists (A) = \{ X \subseteq  A : X \ne \emptyset \}$.

Comment: Thus, we can define the usual *boolean operations* on them, like e.g. : $(Q \cap Q')(A)=Q(A) \cap Q'(A)$ and : $(-Q)(A)= \{ X⊆A : X \notin Q(A) \}$, because they are sets.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question directly. In what sense is a quantifer a mapping from a boolean algebra to another boolean algebra? I suppose that this is true in the sense that, given a boolean algebra can be associated with the powerset of a set, and a quantifier maps a powerset to a powerset. Is that what you are getting at?

Comment: You can see also [Generalized Quantifiers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/#univ).

Comment: Further details into Keenan & Stavi, [A semantic characterization of natural language determiners](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25001246?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), Appendix, page 317.

Comment: The "semantics" of Keenan & Savi is (more or less) : $E$ is the universe (set of "individuals") and $P_E$ is the set of *properties*; but a property is a subset of $E$ and thus $P_E$ is $\mathcal P(E)$.

Comment: A *determiner* is a function from $P_E$ to $P^*$ where $P^*$ in turn is the set of all subsets of $P_E$.

Comment: "Some boys" is the quantifier "some" applied to the "property "boy" of universe $E$. Thus it has the form $Q(B)$ with $B \subset E$. To say "pointwise" means that we have to consider the algebra of the quantifiers (of functions) for a "fixed" $B$, i.e. for a fixed subset of the universe $E$.